# Confidence intervals in R, not shown in output

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a small panel dataset with 7 cities, for 5 years, with the characteristic Population (Pop).
I'm trying to plot with plotmeans function this: 
`plotmeans(Pop~City)`. In the output are shown only the means, but the confidence intervals are missing.

Also, when I run `plotmeans(Pop~Year)`, the output resulted is fine, it has confidence intervals.

What might be the problem?

An example - with 5 years, 5 companies, and their profit:

[left - 95% confidence interval for the average profit of each company, right - 95% confidence interval for companies' average profit of each year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRA7P.png)

Code used:
`plotmeans(Profit~Company)`
`plotmeans(Profit~Year)`

My code:
`plotmeans(Pop~City)`
`plotmeans(Pop~Year)`

My output:

[My output for each City - if you notice, for the first year, there are some blue lines that represent the confidence interval and for the second year, there are 2 blue dots... But that's all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8622.png)

[My output for each year - resulted fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f0YZ.png)

Comment: Does it make sense to talk of confidence intervals for cities?

Comment: @Hugh, it's a part of the project I have to do for my Master exam. The teacher has given us an example with countries, and said we could take as input countries, cities, companies, ...